# pl/sql:error msg SP2-0552: Variable de lien "NEW" non déclarée

Tags: plsql

ps: iam a beginner with pl/sql
i have some problems with this trigers.it doesn't work

```
create or replace TRIGGER T_sal_emp 
Before INSERT OR UPDATE of sal
ON EMP
for each row
Begin
    if (:New.sal>5000) then 
        Raise_application_error(-20001,'emp ne doit pas depasser 5000'); 
    end if; 
end;
/
```

**error sg:**

**SP2-0552: Variable de lien "NEW" non déclarée**

Comment: Your trigger works perfectly as is for me. No errors. Are you sure that's all your relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

```
It works for me. See below snippet of yours with compiled state.

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_sal_emp Before
  INSERT OR
  UPDATE OF sal ON EMP FOR EACH row 
  BEGIN 
  IF (:New.sal>5000) THEN 
  Raise_application_error(-20001,'emp ne doit pas depasser 5000');
END IF;
END;

----------------------------OUTPUT--------------------------------------------------

OWNER   OBJECT_NAME STATUS  OBJECT_TYPE
AVROY   T_SAL_EMP   VALID   TRIGGER

----------------------------OUTPUT-------------------------------------------------
```